# jQuery to get value of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, html.textboxfor

I need to write some jQuery/javascript to do some validation before submitting a form, because I have to check per some very specific results.  Per my tests I believe I am accessing the correct row of data as $(this) in my table with my validation tests, however I cannot get the value typed into the text box of the second td of the row.  Something is incorrect with:

`alert($(this).closest('td').find($("input[name=test]")).val())`

which is preventing the jQuery from getting the value typed into the test textbox of the html below.

```
<tr>
<td>
    <select id="selectId3" name="selectId3" data-val-required="The selectId3 field is required." data-val-number="The field selectId3 must be a number." data-val="true">
        <option value="">-- Select Area --</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <span style="label2">
        <input id="test" type="text" value="" name="test">
    </span>
</td>
<td>   </td>
```

```
$('#myForm').submit(function () {
    $("select").each(function () {
        if (($(this).val() != '') && ($(this).val() != '-- Select Area --')) {
            alert($(this).closest('td').find($("input[name=test]")).val());
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

If anyone can describe the correct jQuery to get the textbox value I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`closest()` travels up the DOM tree, not down, so if `$(this)` equals the current row, you will never find the `td` tags inside it using `closest('td')`.

Assuming that you can't simply use the `id` attribute to access the `input` directly, as Jamie suggested, you would need to use:

```
$(this).children("td:eq(0)");
```

. . . to get the first `td` of the row, assuming that `$(this)` references the row that you want.  To access the value of the select inside it, use:

```
$(this).children("td:eq(0)").find("select").val();
```

**EDIT:** Actually, given your code, there are a whol bunch of ways that you could access the value of that `select` element, but it's hard to tell which would be the most efficient without seeing the rest of the code, to know the context of the logic.

**UPDATE:**  Based on your comments below, try this for your code:

```
$(this).closest("tr").children("td:eq(0)").find("select").val();
```

. . . or . . .

```
$(this).closest("tr").children("td:eq(0) select").val();
```

*(the first one is faster)*

Comment: $(this) in my script references the <select> which is in the cell (td) just before the cell which contains the input textbox that I need to get the value from.  Both the reference of $(this) and the cell I need to get the value from are in the same row (tr).  So I am think the following is closer to what I need but still not working:                    alert($(this).parent('tr').find('td:eq(0) input').val());  -- any addition advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `closest("tr")`, not `parent("tr")` . . . the parent of the `<select>` is the `<td>`.  Change that and it should work.

Comment: talemyn - I didn't use the exact function that you posted but it was very close and your suggestion set me in the right direction, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Access it by id?

```
$("#test").val();
```

The # in this example means find an element by its id ([jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/))

Answer (score 0):

```
 var textboxvalue= $(this).closest('td:eq(1) input').val();
```

eq is 0 based, if 1 for then second td,for textbox we use `input`